# Why I can't overfit a single batch (the loss keeps oscilating)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am training simple feedforward neural network for regression task and I am just trying to overfit single batch of 32 examples (with 9 features) to see if the implementation is ok, however, the loss keeps oscilating no matter the learning rate and hidden size I try, it looks like this:
[image]

The data is standard scaled. The network is just having one hidden layer with ReLU:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
LR = 0.0001
NUM_EPOCHS = 100
HIDDEN_SIZE = 512

class FullyConnected(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size=HIDDEN_SIZE):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=in_features, out_features=hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_size, out_features=1)
        
    def forward(self, x): 
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
```

And the training loop is the usual one, except the fact that I am just overfitting for now a single batch:

```
model = FullyConnected().to(device)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LR)
model.train()

X, y = next(iter(train_dataloader))

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    y_pred = model(X)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Why I can't overfit a single batch and the loss is oscilating in a weird way despite the learning rate being small?

Comment: What range of learning rates have you tried? I would start with something very small, like 1e-7. If you go all the way to zero you certainly shouldn't see any oscillations.

Comment: yes, I tried that, it seems to just decrease the magnitude of oscillation a bit.

Comment: What I found really puzzling though is that I discovered that the issue disappears when I change `shuffle` to `False` in `train_dataloader`, so basically putting data unshuffled is fixing the problem, which is quite weird as the data come from time series